# iOS - track which ad campaigns my installs are coming from

Tags: ios, app-store

I have an iOS application on the app store and I am running a few ad campaigns (Google Adwords, FB Ads, etc.). How do I know where my installs are coming from?

I have an equivalent Android app, and Google play allows me to append a ?ref parameter to the PlayStore URL which I can then retrieve using a Broadcast Receiver within the application. I can append information such as the campaign details, the time of the click, etc.

How can I do with with the Apple AppStore?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly. Instead, direct the ad clicks through a page on your own web server which logs your analytics and then immediately redirects to the app store URL.

Comment: After logging the click data, and the user installs the app - how do we put these two pieces back together? That is, how do we know which click resulted in which install?

Comment: @AndyHin, You could call home when launching the app, and maybe match up by IP address. You're not going to get any better with adwords and fb ads, but you will get this with services like freemyapps.com.

Comment: You can't. The click analytics you can store will only tell you that a user went to the app store via a certain ad, not that they actually installed. Probably the best you could do would be to (anonymously) record the IP address of the ad click and the IP address on first open of your app. They won't always correlate though. You would get an accurate view on which ads drove users to the store and a generalised view on which ads drove the most installs.

Comment: i guess you can use hashed mac adress instead of ip adress, which is always gives the same value from the same device.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing. I came across this question of Quora which has numerous answers. They all claim to provide an answer to whether the user installed the app.
http://www.quora.com/How-can-you-track-referrals-that-go-through-the-Apple-App-Store