# iOS Conversion / installation Tracking

Tags: ios, ios7, google-analytics-firebase

**Objective:** i want to fetch my custom parameter(referrer) from iTunes link upon installation of my application in device.

**iTunes** links look somethings like this:
https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/complete-gym-guide-lite/id550449574?mt=8

If i append my parameter say(&referrer=xyz)at the end and i open this url in ios safari browser then it will prompt to download the application.

**Confusion:** will app store send my parameter(referrer) to my application on launch so that i can fetch it in my application and use it.

In case of **Android play store** link look like this: http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=&referrer=guid%3D%guid%

As you can see referrer parameter at the end of url. Once app is installed in device then play store will send this parameter to app using INSTALL_REFERRER broadcast receiver. We can use this parameter.

**What i tried OR Other people doing for conversion tracking**: Other people are simply sending static data to their server at the first time opening of app and maintain a flag in NSDefault to make sure that app does not send same data again. I can also do the same as well as alternate ways suggested in below links but i want to do something with custom parameter.

I have already seen below links:
[iOS - track which ad campaigns my installs are coming from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909077/ios-track-which-ad-campaigns-my-installs-are-coming-from)
[Tracking iOS installs from multiple marketing sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231351/tracking-ios-installs-from-multiple-marketing-sources)

Please help me out.

Comment: Hi Aditya, sorry that I cannot help you with this. In contrast, I am facing exactly the same problem. So, were you able to solve your problem by now?

Comment: There is no solution for this problem. Apple does not pass any data from apple store to application like referrer and all...

Answer (score 0):

As @Aditya said, for now, Apple is not sending any referrer (or params) from iTunes to installation.

The only way you have it's to use a third party sdk to get your installations.

I have been working on a own sdk to get this but the way to get any info it's really hard and not really confident to use it. So endly we used some third party which are using many techniques to getting this (as fingerprint data, App2App methods, etc...)

I have tested appsflyer sdk and facebook sdk, they work as expected, use this or any else you prefer.

Hope this helps